# Registering AngularJS components via providers

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm implementing an Angular/RequireJS routing solution based on [Dan Wahlin's article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx).

In the article, Dan makes the following register shortcuts on his app object:

```
app.register =
{
    controller: $controllerProvider.register,
    directive: $compileProvider.directive,
    filter: $filterProvider.register,
    factory: $provide.factory,
    service: $provide.service
};
```

When I use these, I can correctly register and reference my controllers through RequireJS calls, but if I use the traditionall `app.controller()` or `angular.module('myApp').controller()` syntax, then Angular can't find them and I get errors from the router.

How is defining controllers, directives, etc. with the above method different, and why does it work with RequireJS where the more traditional method does not?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
-Nate

Answer (score 0):

Since the controllers are being added dynamically things have to change a bit from the "norm" (unfortunately). The main difference is that controllers are being wrapped in RequireJS modules, being downloaded dynamically, and then being registered. The $controllerProvider.register allows for the dynamic registration. It's definitely not the normal technique but what's required in this scenario. That's why "app" (which is the RequireJS module that gets us to the application's AngularJS module) is passed in to all of the controller modules. It exposes the controller property shown above which handles the registration "on the fly".

If you download a controller script dynamically and then use the normal technique (angular.module('..').controller(..)) it won't register it properly - at least that was the case the last time I tried it. It's been several months since I've tried it but I'm assuming the same behavior is still there.

The bottom line is that when controllers (and other items such as services/factories) have scripts that are loaded "on the fly" things change somewhat and the way you access and register these items changes from the normal way that we're all used to seeing.

Comment: Dan, any idea *why* the standard technique won't work? Does it not use the providers? I'm trying to understand the why's behind the situation so that if there are other differences we're prepared for them. Any idea of the technical differences between `app.module('app').controller()` and `$controllerProvider.register()`?